# Android - Launching activity from notification while screen is locked causes crash

Tags: android, notifications, lockscreen

THERE ARE NO ERRORS IN MY LOGCAT

I have my notification being launched from a timer which then sets off a broadcastreciever that triggers my notification. This all works fine and when a user unlocks the screen and then presses the notification it properly launches the activity. However when the screen is locked and a user pulls down the notification bar and launches the activity from there it causes the app to crash instead of launching.

Is this because there is no current backstack or valid context for the map? There should be because when I unlock the screen first it works.

Also Ive run through some basic tests and have close the app completely then turned off the screen and opened it back up and tried when its locked and got the crash and then Ive also opened the app after the screen is unlocked it works perfect.

So....why would having the screen locked make a difference and cause the app to crash when launching the notifications intent from the lockscreen.

Comment: Theres not one error in the logcat. The app just closes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not much to go on here and I would have put this in comments (not enough points), but you need to fire up the debugger and place breakpoints where you 'think' the code is failing.  You said there are no Logcat messages, so you should should make sure you are catching whatever exceptions you can and printing the stacktraces.  Remember, you don't have to use try/catch ONLY when it's required...

Also make sure you are adding in a healthy dose of your own logging messages so that you can trace the functioning of the app as it runs.

Sorry, I know this is not an answer, but without any code or stacktrace it's tough :) good luck!

Comment: No worries its all good. Ive figured that when launching from the lockscreen the app cant get current context fast enough to perform operations on a map fragment. Any other activity I try launches just fine. Its only when I launch a map that it throws a fit and closes with no messages what so ever. If it gave me an error at least I would be able to know where I could try placing some catch blocks.

Comment: How did you check for the context?